# How to retrieve data from three tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables

```
table1                    table2                          table3
---------------          ----------------------------          ---------------------
NO.    courses           NO.   id        courses    grade          NO.       courses
---------------          -----------------------------         ---------------------
1      CHEM 101          1    2255      CHEM 101    A+             2         English    
2      ENGL 101          2    2255      English     A
3      MATH 101
```

How I can write SQL query to retrieve data by id from previous tables in order to give me like this table  where the relation between them is NO.

```
----------------------------------------
course     grade     equal of my courses
----------------------------------------
CHEM 101   A+            null
ENGL 101   A             English   
MATH 101   null          null
```

Comment: Check out LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for. I assume NO is a column name that maintain the relationship between all tables

```
SELECT t1.courses,t2.grade,t3.courses AS 'equal of my courses'
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.NO = t2.NO
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.NO = t3.NO;
```

Comment: How I retrieve the data by id

Comment: in your query there is no any id column ? but if you filter out by id you can add where clause

Answer (score 1):

You need a PK and a FK on the tables to join them up together, otherwise its sort of a crapshoot in your example.