# HOW I filter out three tables by id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables in my database

```
table1                    table2                          table3
---------------          ----------------------------          ---------------------
NO.    courses           NO.   id        courses    grade          NO.       courses
---------------          -----------------------------         ---------------------
1      CHEM 101          1    2255      CHEM 101    A+             2         English    
2      ENGL 101          2    2255      English     A
3      MATH 101          1    2244      CHEM 101    A+
```

I wrote SQL query to retrieve the data from the previous tables in order to show me table like this

```
----------------------------------------
course     grade     equal of my courses
----------------------------------------
CHEM 101   A+            null
ENGL 101   A             English   
MATH 101   null          null
```

the query is

```
SELECT t1.courses,t2.grade,t3.courses AS 'equal of my courses'
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.NO = t2.NO
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.NO = t3.NO;
```

It work fine but how I filter out by id ?

Comment: this is wrong way. you copy question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177506/how-to-retrieve-data-from-three-tables-in-sql/36177654#36177654 and made another question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the where clause. Replace 1 with the id that you want to filter by.

```
SELECT t1.courses,t2.grade,t3.courses AS 'equal of my courses'
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.NO = t2.NO
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.NO = t3.NO
WHERE t2.id = 1;
```